# Pie charts and bar graphs using selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver, bar-chart, pie-chart

How to automate pie charts and bar graphs using selenium. And the charts are generated as Images ?

Thanks in Advance,
Degaleesan.P

Comment: is the charting utility/plugin/library being built in your org that you want to test or is it some 3rd party charting library? If it's 3rd party, then why do you want to test it?

Comment: `Selenium/Webdriver` is a tool to allow automation of websites and webapps. Are you sure it is the right tool for what you want to do?

Comment: @Mark Rowlands: I know that selenium can automate the graphs and charts. But i don know, it is possible to automate the images.. ?

Example:  X-axis show year like 2010,2011,2012,2013 and Y-axis shows 10,20,30,40 . I need to verify the bar value with the DB.  If the DB value =13.5, need to verify the Bar chart value =13.5 or not...

Comment: @AbhijeetVaikar : Kindly check the above comments

Comment: If the charts get generated as svg/images/canvas elements on your web page then you won't be able to verify them using Selenium. If they get generated as html elements then you should be able to do it. Easiest way to verify would be to inspect the element on your browser checking whether the chart is one of the above things.

Comment: Your solution is in my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42641307/selenium-python-mouse-hover-on-pie-chart-with-small-sections-hovers-on-wrong-se